# VBA for calculating the difference on Shift Hours Calculation

Tags: sql, vba, excel, adodb

I am trying to get the worked hours for each employee with the swipe report based on the EventType (In or Out) using VBA/SQL.

So far I've got the Total Logon hours but unable to calculate the in-between breaks from the Enter/Exit split. Can anyone please help me pointing in to a correct direction.

```
SELECT 
    StaffMember, Date, 
    min(EventDateTime) as Max_In, 
    max(EventDateTime) as Max_Out, 
    (max(EventDateTime)- min(EventDateTime))*24 as Whrs
From [data$] 
group by StaffMember, Date
```

[image: Example Set]

Comment: What RDMBS are you using? This looks like SQL Server. Very important as SQL dialects differ among databases.

Answer (score 1):

If your SQL flavor supports windowed functions you can approach it like this:

```
SELECT Entrances.StaffMember,
       EnterTime,
       ExitTime,
       ExitTime - EnterTime As TimeBetween
  FROM (SELECT StaffMember,
               EventDateTime As EnterTime,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                 ( PARTITION BY StaffMember
                       ORDER BY EventDateTime ASC
                 ) As EnterRnk
          FROM data
         WHERE EventType = 'Enter'
       ) AS Entrances
 INNER /*
        Or left join and coalesce to a high value
        if you don't want to drop anything
       */
  JOIN (SELECT StaffMember,
               EventDateTime As ExitTime,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                 ( PARTITION BY StaffMember
                       ORDER BY EventDateTime ASC
                 ) As ExitRnk
          FROM data
         WHERE EventType = 'Exit'
       ) AS Exits
    ON Entrances.StaffMember = Exits.StaffMember
   AND Entrances.EnterRnk = Exits.ExitRnk
```

Otherwise you'll have to see if it supports recursive queries.